# Is design of "Budweiser's bow-tie shaped beer can " feasible & unique from engineering point of view?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, product-engineering

Is design of "Budweiser's bow-tie shaped beer can " feasible & unique from engineering point of view?
Can there be a better design than it?

Like the shape of can is inclined at ten degree & appears easy to crush it? Is there any other advantage/disadvantage of this design? Please help me. [image]

Comment: What is the point of the question, something about patents?

Comment: Where is it claimed it's feasible and unique? Appears to be a standard 12 oz can with an extra forming step, which is "unique" but not any more feasible than a regular can. Didn't they stop making these years ago as well?

Comment: Sir i wanted to research about the design of this bear can, even this shape contain less bear . what was designers motive to launch it.

Comment: @ solar mike sir, really funny, I edited it? Help me if you can, thanks

Comment: American Budweiser has several marketing problems, one is their beer and the other is that they share the name with a beer that's actually good. I presume the shape is purely marketing.

Comment: Pure marketing. Little or no relevance to engineering.

Comment: 2010 development and 2013 deployment does imply some engineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Budweiser made some design modification to regain its marketing and branding endeavours which had seen  huge decline in sales threatening Budweiser's status as America's Best selling beer. The new design emphasized the iconic bowtie and updated its appearance giving it a eye-catching look, providing good holding experience which was easy to grip.

After can modification Due to Can's slimmer middle and sleek design it contained lesser amount of bear than its traditional design.
In packaging terms, it took twice as much aluminium as normal canes which increased its production cost.

So the  new modification failed to impress the customer, instead of focussing on can appearance they would have focussed on taste of beer and should not make compromise on quantity of beer.

Comment: No that I don't believe you but do you have sources? specifically the aluminum amount.

Comment: @mart Sir a simple google search can help you. Yes it took twice aluminum than it's old design.

Comment: Source:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.phaidon.com/agenda/design/articles/2013/april/29/budweiser-introduces-new-bow-tie-can/%23:~:text%3DThe%2520new%252011.3%252Dounce%2520can,is%252C%2520of%2520course%252C%2520recyclable.&ved=2ahUKEwj3oLKQ3srrAhVUVH0KHWZuCw8QFjABegQIChAG&usg=AOvVaw31h9aaoPevqlo8d40lwm_h

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 2):

A merchandise container design is a fusion of art, marketing, branding, nudging public opinion, and many more factors.

This design is bold, exciting, and stands out from the shelf in the store to when you hold it in your hand to when you discard it.

It has been so successful that has made its way here even.

Seems they have surmounted the manufacturing problems of stepping out of the age-old confines of sheet aluminum.

Remember Apple, how the elegant, unique, clean lines of iPhones and iPads helped them to become what they are now. Many of their competitors are long gone.

Comment: Thank you  sir, can the target  of  company be achieved  by better  and simple  design  or marketing  strategies.

Comment: The real plus for Apple is the control they have about how the software integrates with the hardware... remember the pc issue with defining expanded memory versus extended memory and how programs would work with one and not the other. Apple and Atari avoided that, which meant they crashed less often.

Comment: Markeing is a very complicated issue. This is certainly a marketing feat. They study extensively about the public reception to new ideas. We live and think the way they've formed us to be. I watch the same TV program on 2 different brands, i feel i have watch a different show. I believe they should start to give Nobel prize for marketing.

Comment: Another example of this the age old curved Coca Cola glass bottle.

Comment: but can they put something in it besides Budweiser?